# Оплата через эквайринг Сбербанк

Tags: javascript

Данный код при нажатии на кнопку "Купить" выводит окно Сбербанка для оплаты с ценой 499,99

```
<a onclick="ipayCheckout({
    amount:499.99,
    currency:'RUB',
    order_number:'',
    description: 'Тариф'},
    function(order) { showSuccessfulPurchase(order) },
    function(order) { showFailurefulPurchase(order) })"
     
    class="btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-primary">Купить
</a>
```

Мне необходимо это сделать с условием. В зависимости от выбора в форме регистрации, после нажатия на кнопку "Отправить" выходило окно с оплатой и ценой тарифного плана, выбранного в :

```
<select>

 <option>Тариф "Теория"</option>
 <option>Тариф "Практикум"</option>

</select>
```

Есть понимание что это делается при помощи `if` и `else`, но как не понимаю.

Comment: Вызывайте ipayCheckout через свою функцию, в которой будут учтены ваши пожелания.

P.S. Не рекомендую вам заниматься финансовыми операциями, учитывая ваш уровень знаний в данной сфере... чревато как бы...

Comment: В рамках стандартной проверки первого вопроса  я постарался включить ваш код правильно. Но JS я не знаю, проверьте, что все правильно отображается. Если нет - исправьте по аналогии.